# Clipping vector polygonised from raster

Tags: raster, vector, clip, raster-conversion, polygonize

I have vector created by conversion of a raster to vector operation. I want to clip this vector file.
While I am trying to do that, I am getting the below mentioned error:

**Feature (355) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution failed after 0.05 seconds**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using QGIS? Try "Fix geometries" tool on the invalid vector layer

Comment: What GIS software are you using?